# Why do I get "Uncaught SyntaxError" while parsing JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, websocket

I am currently struggling with a JSON string that I receive from my server application.

This is the JavaScript snippet that receives the JSON string:

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://'+location.hostname+':81/', ['arduino']);

connection.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('Received from server: ', e.data);
    var response = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if(response.action=="networks") {
        console.log('SSID: ', response.ssid);
    }
};
```

I get this response in my browser's console according to my `console.log` call above:

```
Received from server:  {"action":"networks","ssid":"UPC6288862","rssi":-69,"enc":8}
```

Ending in the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 60
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocket.connection.onmessage (WebSocket.js:19)
connection.onmessage@WebSocket.js:19
```

When I manually put the string, to JSON.parse() like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"action":"networks","ssid":"UPC Wi-Free","rssi":-42,"enc":255}');
```

the parsing works and I can access the fields by `response.action` for example.

But why I get the error? Is `e.data` not a proper string or do I need to add some quotes or similar to `e.data` before parsing?

UPDATE:

Here's a screenshot of Chrome's network tab while receiving the JSON string via the WebSocket.js:

[image]

Comment: Change the `console.log()` to `console.log(typeof e.data);`

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I get `string` as a result. So what could be the problem?

Comment: how does the response look in your Network tab? the token mentioned is a space. must be an encoding issue

Comment: What is the char code at position 60 of the data?

Comment: My server app is running on a ESP8266 and the JSON string are sent from there with a fixed size of 128 bytes. Probably the padding makes problems. I will update my initial question with a link to a screenshot.

Comment: there you go, you need to trim that somehow. try `e.data.trim()` although not really the function's purpose, then check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229262/match-non-printable-non-ascii-characters-and-remove-from-text

Comment: Yes indeed, the padded values messed the string up. I already tried `trim()`?  but didn't remove the redundant characters (somehow not recognized as spaces). However, `e.data.substring(0, e.data.lastIndexOf("}")+1)` did the job. Thank you very much for your help!