# javascript: Detect and remove invisible characters when pasting text

Tags: javascript, text

I copied a text from a source and pasted it in a textarea.
In the textarea, the text looks OK, but when I paste the text in a text editor like Sublime Text, here's what I see : the string contains some invisible characters in place of 2 spaces (<0x03>).

What are these characters ? Where do they come from ?
With Javascript, how can I detect these and replace with "real" spaces

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24231346/1221208 here you can find an answer suggesting how to match non-printable characters using regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way to do this just use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

```
let inputString = "Lorem ipsum <0x03> dolor <0x03>";

let modifiedString = inputString.replace(/<0x03>/g, ' ');

console.log(modifiedString);
```

UPDATE:

For finding character with code we can use regular expression:

```
let inputString = "Lorem ipsum <0x03> dolor <0x03>";

let modifiedString = inputString.replace(/\x03/g, ' ');


console.log(modifiedString);
```

Comment: you are matching the literal string `'<0x03>'` and not a character with code `0x03`